# JSP in Spring Boot application yields 404 Error no matter what I do

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'll start off by saying I've looked at and tried the solutions in every question regarding this that I can find. The biggest problem is that most of these solutions are very old, and Spring Boot has changed a lot in the last several years. To be clear, I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782915/spring-boot-jsp-404), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847924/spring-boot-jsp-404-whitelabel-error-page), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012335/error-with-spring-boot-jsp-sample-application), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492210/spring-boot-mvc-jsp-mvn-install-404), and more. I've also read numerous tutorials. Nothing works.

I have a brand new Spring Boot application and I'm trying to get JSP rendering working with it. These are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.4.RELEASE,3)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.4.RELEASE,3)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.4.RELEASE,3)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>[2.8.0,3)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.mkammerer</groupId>
        <artifactId>argon2-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>[2.7,3)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>[8.0.21,9)</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.2,)</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.4.RELEASE,3)</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>[9.0.38,)</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.4.RELEASE,3)</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My project is laid out as follows:

```
- source
  - production
    - java
      - [my source code packages]
    - resources
      - WEB-APP
        - jsp
          - initialization
            - begin.jsp
      - [my resource packages]
  - test
    - java
    - resources
```

"WEB-APP/jsp" is just the latest iteration I've tried. I've tried "WEB-INF/jsp", "META-INF/jsp", "webapp/jsp", no parent (just "jsp"), etc., all with the same results.

I know the parent directories are a bit non-standard, but it's configured correctly in Maven and I've confirmed it's *not* the source of my problems:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>source/production/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>source/production/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

My Application class is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.my.project")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.my.project.repository")
@EntityScan("com.my.project.model")
public class Application
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class);

    public Application()
    {
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        LOGGER.info("Constructing InternalResourceViewResolver[JstlView]");
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-APP/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setRedirectContextRelative(true);
        resolver.setRedirectHttp10Compatible(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class InitializationController
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(InitializationController.class);

    @GetMapping("/initialize_application")
    public String beginInitialization(ModelMap model)
    {
        LOGGER.info("Beginning initialization");
        ...
        LOGGER.info("Returning view");
        return "initialization/begin";
    }
    ...
}
```

On startup I see the "Constructing InternalResourceViewResolver" log entry (my view resolver bean is created). When I go to `/initialize_application`, I get the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 18 21:45:26 CDT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Looking in the log again, I see "Beginning initialization" and "Returning view," so I know that the 404 is for my JSP and not my controller. My controller is working.

Other things I've tried:

- Initially I did not have `@EnableWebMvc` on my application. Without it, the log was empty except my log statements. When I added `@EnableWebMvc`, this is now logged with the 404: `No mapping for GET /WEB-APP/jsp/initialization/begin.jsp` (or whatever other directory I've tried other than "WEB-APP").
- I've tried running this directly on the pure command line with `mvn spring-boot:run`
- I've tried running this in IntelliJ IDEA with a Maven run configuration and command `spring-boot:run` (same result)
- I've tried both `<packaging>jar</packaging>` and `<packaging>war</packaging>`, but neither make a difference, because neither a JAR nor a WAR are ever made. Maven runs the application directly out of the `target/classes` directory instead of creating an artifact.
- When I've tried `WEB-INF` or `META-INF` instead of `WEB-APP` or `webapp` or something else, I've seen a logged warning: `Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/jsp/initialization/begin.jsp]`

I have also confirmed that my JSPs are present in `target/classes/WEB-APP/jsp` (or whatever other directory I've tried other than "WEB-APP"), so they *do* exist.

I'm at a loss how to proceed. I'm beginning to think I need to ditch Spring Boot and stick with a traditional boilerplate Spring Web MVC application with a Servlet config and a Tomcat installation, but I was really excited about the "just runs" aspect of Spring Boot. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

After reading [this Spring documentation about JSP limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations), I now know that I have to use `<packaging>war</packaging>`, and I'm using that now, but it hasn't made a difference. I'm starting to suspect that the underlying problem here is that `maven spring-boot:run` doesn't create a WAR and run it, it just builds everything to `target/classes` and runs it from there.

Also, after finding [this old, official Spring boot samples application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/2.1.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src/main), I've changed my project structure a little:

```
- source
  - production
    - java
      - [my source code packages]
    - resources
      - [my resource packages]
    - webapp
      - META-INF
      - WEB-INF
      - jsp
        - initialization
          - begin.jsp
  - test
    - java
    - resources
```

Updated my view resolver configuration:

```
resolver.setPrefix("/jsp/");
resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
```

And added this to my POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>source/production/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If I run `mvn package`, my WAR gets created correctly (classes and JSPs all where they should be), but neither `mvn spring-boot:run` nor `mvn package spring-boot:run` work—I still get 404 errors resolving my JSPs.

The old Spring Boot sample application linked to above puts the JSPs in `WEB-INF/jsp`, but I can't do that, because that results in the warning `Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/jsp/initialization/begin.jsp]` (and still 404). What's frustrating is that this sample application doesn't exist anymore, nor does any new variation of it. I can't find any updated version that works with the newest version of Spring Boot. The sample application was deleted in 2.2.x.

Comment: Did you create project using `spring initializr`?

Comment: I did not create it with that, no.

Comment: Don't use JSP but something like thymeleaf. That being said if you really want, as the docs state, it only works when using a war and you need to create that by Spring Boot (so ditch the `maven-war-plugin` from your build). You have to add tomcat as a provided dependency, else it won't work, and you have to include jasper as well (for compilation). Then you can either deploy the war file or use `java -jar your.war` to run the application. Also remove the annotations and only leave `@SpringBootApplication` those annotations interfere with auto-config.

Comment: I don't want to use Thymeleaf, I want to use JSP. I have it set to `<packaging>war</packaging>` (see above). Where's the documentation about creating the war with Spring Boot instead of `maven-war-plugin`? I don't see it, and using `<packaging>war</packaging>` automatically adds maven-war-plugin. I did add Tomcat+Jasper as a provided dependencies and JSTL as compile dependency, just like the sample application. The Spring Boot docs say you can run with `mvn spring-boot:run`. They do not say that adding JSPs means you have to use `java -jar`. Without the other annotations my application errors.

Comment: In your "initial" attempt the configuration for the `InternalResourceViewResolver` is also flawed. As the JSP are put in the classpath (as `source/production/rsources` is marked as such and not in a separate web directory. So you should prefix the prefix with `classpath`. Also you shouldn't be using `@EnableWebMvc` as that disables the auto-configuration for spring boot. You also don't have to configure an `InternalResourceViewResolver` but instead you could add `spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/WEB-APP/jsp/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp` to achieve the same.

Comment: However when setting an `InternalResourceViewResolver` to a classpath your servlet container cannot see the JSP as it cannot directly access the classpath. So your JSPs have to be outside the classpath in a directory that can be read by the `JspServlet`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try by changing the scope of `tomcat-embed-jasper` to `provided` as this dependency is needed to compile JSPs.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>[9.0.38,)</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Edit:**

I looked for various `spring-boot + jsp` projects over internet. I noticed that they have they also have `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` with `provided` scope. Can you try this.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>[2.3.4.RELEASE,3)</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

References :

https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-with-jsp-view

**Edit-2 :**

So this time i created a new springboot project. Did bare minimum setup to get jsp rendered. So basically i followed this [tutorial](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/) and my project was running fine.

Then I replaced the pom.xml with yours and the i got the same error you mentioned in the question.

Then while doing trial and error i removed the `<version>[9.0.38,)</version>` from `<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>` and it started working for me.

```
        <!--I have removed version here and it started working for me-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<!--            <version>[9.0.38,)</version>-->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Although i have different directory structure. But as you mentioned that is not the cause of issue.

I have uploaded the project to github. Feel free to pull it run it locally.

[Github](https://github.com/wak786/spring-boot-jsp)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question above. It's actually `initialization` in my folder structure. I am correcting the content of the question.

Comment: Okay, I have fixed the content of the question. Great catch! I just wish it had actually been that easy. Alas, it was not.

Comment: If possible Can you put your project on GitHub. So that we can run the project locally.

Comment: I cannot put my project on GitHub. It's proprietary.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see, until just now, that you had changed your answer. I changed the scope to "provided" and it made no difference. Same warnings and errors, same behavior.

Comment: Okay. Lets keep it with provided scope. I will update you if i anything else.

Comment: Yes, I also have `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` with `provided` scope.

Comment: Any luck running your project?

Comment: Please see the edited answer. I created the project locally and it is working on my local. I have also pushed it on github.

Comment: Have some more info, that if you include in your answer, I will accept your answer as correct answer (this may take several comments)... Your sample app was SUPER helpful. The first thing I figured out was that specifying a version for `tomcat-embed-jasper` wasn't the problem (in fact, if you remove the `<parent>` artifact, you *have* to specify a version). The problem was the `[` and `,)`. For some reason, `<version>9.0.38</version>` works, but neither `[9.0.38,)` nor `[9.0.38,10)` work. That doesn't make sense to me, but it is what it is. *However*, that was not my only problem...

Comment: Next, I tried re-organizing your example to use `source/production` and `source/test` instead of `src/main` and `src/test`. And that's the point I couldn't get it to work anymore. Using `<sourceDirectory>`, `<testSourceDirectory>`, `<resources>`, and `<testResources>` make the classes work, and using `<warSourceDirectory>source/production/webapp</warSourceDirectory>` made the WAR build correctly, but `mvn spring-boot:run` would not work (JSPs just 404'd). ...

Comment: So I left most `source/production` things but moved *just* `source/production/webapp` to `src/main/webapp` and changed `<warSourceDirectory>`. BOOM! It worked. So I started reading through Spring Boot code and found several places where `src/main/webapp` is hard-coded in Spring Boot with no way to configure it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/search?q=%22src%2Fmain%2Fwebapp%22. As such, I've concluded that Spring Boot has no flexibility for alternative project layouts. This is really unfortunate :-(, but thankfully it's OSS, so I can file a bug.

Comment: Woow...Great.!!! Really happy that finally it worked. And really great findings. Thanks for the suggestions. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: FYI, I filled https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23829.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the following location for your web content (which should be outside the classpath AFAIK) `source/production/webapp`. Spring Boot will ignore this due to a hardcoded path in [`DocumentRoot`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/a66c4d3096877b33119366ea9ea165c892b462c8/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/server/DocumentRoot.java#L138) for detection of directories when running from the command-line or IDE (it will work when building a war and running that).

As a workaround you can add a `TomcatContextCustomizer` as a bean to detect the path and set it as the correct base.

```java
package com.my.project;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) 
    {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatContextCustomizer docBaseCustomizer() 
    {
        return new TomcatContextCustomizer() 
        {
            public void customize(Context context) 
            {
                File root = new File("source/production/webapp");
                if (root.exists() && root.isDirectory()) 
                {
                    context.setDocBase(root.getAbsolutePath());
                }        
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Now add the following to your `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**NOTE:** The removal of the other annotations can only be done if your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.my.project` package. It will then automatically detect the other classes (like entities and repositories).